# Foreach das propriedades de uma Classe e exibir na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma View em asp.net mvc da seguinte maneira

```
var Maquina = Model.ListMaquinas;

@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Maquina.Property1 )
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Maquina.Property2 )
...
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Maquina.Property100 )
```

Tudo funciona bem.

Porém como tenho muitos campos decidi fazer um foreach da seguinte maneira:

```
var Maquinas = Model.ListaMaquinas;

@foreach( System.Reflection.PropertyInfo item in Maquinas.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Maquinas.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name) )
}
```

Porém assim o DisplayNameFor não está funcionando estou errando em algum ponto? Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tá errando porque e a variável item que você deve usar e talvez por usar reflexão.

Comment: Tentei usar assim: @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => @item.Name) mas só imprime NameNameName...

Comment: Foi respondido de acordo com a pergunta a resposta foi útil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo para esclarecer a sua duvida:

***Classe***

```
public class People
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

***View:***

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.People
@foreach(var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    @Html.DisplayName(property.Name) @Html.Display(property.Name)
    <br />
}
```

***sendo que:***

- `DisplayName` vai imprimir o texto contido no valor de `Name`
- `Display` vai imprimir o valor dessa propriedade referente o valor de `Name`

***Observação:*** evite usar isso como regra pois, reflexão muitas vezes torna seu código  mais lento e em alguns casos torna isso também desnecessário, então todo cuidado é pouco.

Comment: Virgilio muito obrigado pela resposta e organização da solução! Testei aqui e funcionou! Porém percebi uma coisa:
No meu model eu tenho as DataAnnotations para o nome dos campos, porém com o DisplayName não apareceram.

Sobre sua observação, muito obrigado pela dica. Este relatório será acessado pelos administradores do sistemas poucas vezes e não necessita de performance. Este será um relatório onde irei demonstrar vários relatórios da empresa por 12 meses lado a lado.

Comment: @Accorsi você quis reflexão então precisa fazer mais pra pegar as configurações do DataAnnotations, edite sua pergunta colocando o exemplo da classe e qual valor deve aparecer